# How to retrieve the array of objects having same property value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have a array of object if property `items` has same value, return that array object in javascript

In the below list, retrieve the array of object having same value in

`items` property in javascript

note:also dynamic object array, items value may vary, so cannot directly filter with value

```
var list =[
  {id: 1, name: "dev", items: "sales", code: "IN"},
  {id: 2, name: "lena", items: "finance", code: "SG"}
  {id: 3, name: "lisa", items: "sales", code: "AU"},
  {id: 4, name: "mano", items: "marketing", code: "IN"}
]

Expected Result
 {id: 1, name: "dev", items: "sales", code: "IN"}
 {id: 3, name: "lisa", items: "sales", code: "AU"},


var result= list.reduce((m, o) => {
  const found= m.find(e => e.items === o.items);
  if(found){
   m.push(o);
   return m
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reduce it's more cumbersome to find out all duplicates.
You can use closure.

```js
const list = [
  { id: 1, name: "dev", items: "sales", code: "IN" },
  { id: 2, name: "lena", items: "finance", code: "SG" },
  { id: 3, name: "lisa", items: "sales", code: "AU" },
  { id: 4, name: "mano", items: "marketing", code: "IN" },
  { id: 5, name: "lisa", items: "gul gul", code: "AU" },
  { id: 6, name: "anthony", items: "some", code: "AU" },
  { id: 7, name: "mark", items: "gul gul", code: "AU" }
];

const findByItems = (eq) => (arr) => arr.filter(
  (x, i) => arr.find((y, j) => i !== j && eq(x, y))
)

const duplicatedItems = findByItems((a, b) => a.items === b.items);


console.log(duplicatedItems(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally group the items in the input by their *items* values, and then extract the one with the longest group (in your example, finance and marketing would have one item and only sales would have two):

```
var list = [
  {id: 1, name: "dev", items: "sales", code: "IN"},
  {id: 2, name: "lena", items: "finance", code: "SG"},
  {id: 3, name: "lisa", items: "sales", code: "AU"},
  {id: 4, name: "mano", items: "marketing", code: "IN"}
]

const map = {}
for (let item of list) {
  if (map[item.items]) {
    map[item.items].push(item);
  } else {
    map[item.items] = [item]
  }
}

let maxLength = 0, result;
for (let key in map) {
  if (map[key].length > maxLength) {
    maxLength = map[key].length
    result = map[key]
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

This will return

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'dev', items: 'sales', code: 'IN' },
  { id: 3, name: 'lisa', items: 'sales', code: 'AU' }
]
```

as you were expecting.